# rightBarButtonItem does not appear in Navigation Bar iOS

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I'm having problems displaying the rightBarButtonItem of the Navigation Bar - I'm attempting to create it programmatically in the Application Delegate, where my UINavigationController is set up.

Code is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
RSCListViewController *list = [[RSCListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:list];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:list
                                                             action:@selector(addPressed:)];

self.navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[DatabaseManager openDatabase];

return YES;
}
```

Running the application, no button item appears on the navigation bar.

I'm not sure whether I have missed something obvious - my attempts to rectify the problem using related Stack Overflow threads haven't yielded any success.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: everything else displays correctly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to attach your bar button item to your custom view controller, not to the navigation controller. From [Updating the Navigation Bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW25):

> In addition, the navigation controller object builds the contents of
>   the navigation bar dynamically using the navigation items (instances
>   of the UINavigationItem class) associated with the view controllers on
>   the navigation stack. To change the contents of the navigation bar,
>   you must therefore configure the navigation items for your custom view
>   controllers.
>
> (...)
>
> The navigation controller updates the right side of the navigation bar
>   as follows:
>
> - If the new top-level view controller has a custom right bar button item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom right bar button
>     item, set the rightBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s
>     navigation item.
> - If no custom right bar button item is specified, the navigation bar displays nothing on the right side of the bar.

Therefore, replace:

```
self.navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

with:

```
list.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: Thanks - had assumed that the elements displayed on the navigation bar were tied to the navigation controller rather than the view at the top of the stack... but now I think about it, this wouldn't make much sense as the navigation bar will often change as a result of which view is being displayed. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: For some reason that does not work when the VC whose navigationItem you set rightBarButtonItem is the rootViewController :-( But, as you said, it works fine whenever the vc with @navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = whatever;" is pushed onto nav stack though.

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: No, you should not use the class name. The variable `list` refers to an instance of the class. In the question, the `rightBarButtonItem` is set from outside the class.